# Zygmund Measure and Integral Theorem 3.29

Tags: solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

> Suppose the $|E|_e<\infty$. Then $E$ is measurable if and only if given $\epsilon>0$, $E=(S\cup N_1)-N_2$, where $S$ is a finite union of nonoverlapping intervals and $|N_1|_e,|N_2|_e<\epsilon$.

*Proof.* Sufficiency. For each $n$, choose $N^n_j$ so that $|N^n_j|_e<1/n$ and $E=(S\cup N^n_1)-N^n_2$. Since $|\bigcap_n N^n_j|_e\leq |N^n_j|_e<1/n$ for all $n$, $\bigcap N^n_1$ and $\bigcap N^n_2$ are measurable. Observe that $E=(S\cup\bigcap N^n_1)-\bigcap N^n_2$. Thus $E$ is measurable. 
Necessity. Let $\epsilon>0$. There exist an open set $G$ and countably many nonoverlapping intervals $\{I_n\}$ such that $E\subset G$, $|G-E|<\epsilon$, and $G=\bigcup I_n$. Hence $\sum|I_n|<|E|+\epsilon$. Since $|E|<\infty$, by the Cauchy criterion, $\sum^\infty_{n=N+1}|I_n|<\epsilon$ for some $N$. Put $S=\bigcup^N_{n=1} I_n$ and $N_1=\bigcup^\infty_{n=N+1}I_n$. Then $|N_1|<\epsilon$ and $|N_2|=|S\cup N_1-E|=|G-E|<\epsilon$.

Is this correct?

Comment: why your S doesn't depends on the given epsilon?